# Code Igniter (Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string) erro

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, codeigniter

this is my model:

```
function Countosweb(){
    $sql="SELECT count(*) FROM `os` WHERE `status`='PENDIENTE ASIGNAR TÉCNICO'";
    return $this->db->query($sql)->row();
}
```

this is my controller:

```
public function indexp() {
    if((!$this->session->userdata('session_id')) || (!$this->session->userdata('logado'))){
        redirect('mapos/login');
    }
    $this->data['ordensW'] = $this->mapos_model->getOsWeb();
    $this->data['osn']= $this->mapos_model->Countosweb($sql);
    $this->data['ordens'] = $this->mapos_model->getOsAbertas();
    $this->data['produtos'] = $this->mapos_model->getProdutosMinimo();
    $this->data['os'] = $this->mapos_model->getOsEstatisticas();
    $this->data['estatisticas_financeiro'] = $this->mapos_model->getEstatisticasFinanceiro();
    $this->data['menuPainel'] = 'Painel';
    $this->data['view'] = 'mapos/panel';
    //$this->session->set_flashdata('success','mensaje de prueba');
    $this->load->view('tema/alte',$this->data);

}
```

and this is my view:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
                <?php
                if($osn != null){echo '<span class="label label-warning">'.$osn.'</span>';} // this is the line which is occasinating the problem.
                ?>
           </a>
```

so i got this error:

A PHP ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED

```
Severity: 4096

Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Filename:tema/alte.php

line Number: 67
```

Please help to find the problem

PD: excuse me, my english is not very good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all for helping me, i solved it:

i changed this:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
            <?php
            if($osn != null){echo '<span class="label label-warning">'.$osn.'</span>';} // this is the line which is occasinating the problem.
            ?>   
</a>
```

For this:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
                <?php
                if($osn != null){
                  foreach($osn as $on){echo'<span class="label label-warning">'.$on.'</span>';} 
                }
                ?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use echo to print Object - the return value in ordinary case is object or arrayuse :

```
 print_r($osn) ;
```

to see the output then loop through it or use object [$object_name->item]

Answer (score 0):

I advice you change your function to this as to get the number of rows returned.

```
function Countosweb(){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `os` WHERE `status`='PENDIENTE ASIGNAR TÉCNICO'";
    return $this->db->query($sql)->num_rows();
}
```

Then your html should look like this.

```
<a href="#" 
   class="dropdown-toggle" 
   data-toggle="dropdown">

   <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
   <?php
       if(isset($osn)){
           echo '<span class="label label-warning">'.$osn.'</span>';
       } // this is the line which is occasinating the problem.
   ?>
</a>
```

Comment: kindly paste the result of var_dump($osn);

Comment: I just went through creating a sample db with your controller and the models with the option above and it works fine. Please, do go through the correction above once more. And if you can kindly, paste your var_dump($osn).

Comment: be sure that osn column has value in it . if there is a value just var_dump() and print by right way .